# How can I programmatically compile an adobe air application from within an existing air application at runtime?

Tags: air, adobe, cross-platform

Hi I'm trying to find out if I can create a new adobe air application using an existing running adobe air application and dynamically add a sql lite db and resources (excel files, pdfs, etc) to it to create custom air applications on the fly, which can then be run cross platform.

I believe I would have to run/use the ADT package program to create and package the custom air file.
and I think 'd have to get the running air application to run ADT from the command line to programmatically create the adobe air application.

Is this possible?

thank you,

Carlos

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to call the AIR compiler using some native command API, but it sounds like a security vulnerability waiting to happen.

Whenever people ask to do something like this, they usually are wanting to build some sort of template-based application that can be populated with custom data. If this is what you're looking for, it is much better to define a database schema that can store these values and hook it up to an entry form (or a few). You can write a separate binary that connects to this database at runtime, fetches the configuration parameters and customizes the UI / displays the content / whatever.